# Which file should I refer to? /proc/self/mounts or /proc/self/mountinfo?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount

In some places I can see that people are suggesting to avoid using /proc/self/mounts file as it is deprecated. However, I don't see any such thing in the official documentation: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html

Apart from the fact that mounts file has some missing information, is there any other reason one must prefer mountinfo file?

Comment: This is your third post about the same subject in 24 hours.

Comment: Yes, I am working on something related to filesystems.